# Updated: TENSORFLOW Activating Virtualenv through Terminal is not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow, virtualenv

macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 — MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2016)
Trying to set up Python TensorFlow NOT because I like Python (hate it) but because that was what was recommended 
NOTE: Not very experienced with Terminals and whatnot, but an okay programmer.

NEW PROBLEMS:

 My computer seemed to have downloaded TensorFlow, but when following the steps to test it, this showed up: 
`Macbook:~ rose$ cd Desktop
Macbook:Desktop rose$ Python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow`

EVERYTHING seemed fine when I finished the steps for installation...

So, I was thinking today that it would be pretty awesome to see if I could figure out how to set up some sort of neural network programming environment on my computer and eventually found TensorFlow. Everything was going pretty well, I was just [following the instructions on this page at the official site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac) for instructions. I installed pip, Virtualenv, nose/tornado (said I needed them, created a Virtualenv environment for Python 3.n, which I updated to today, then got to this step:

> Activate the Virtualenv environment by issuing one of the following  commands:
>   
> `$ cd targetDirectory`
>   
> `$ source ./bin/activate      # If using bash, sh, ksh, or zsh`
>   
>  `$ source ./bin/activate.csh  # If using csh or tcsh`

I used the command it said to use for bash (wow, these names are horrible and nondescript), but I'm not 100% sure I use bash, almost certain because that is supposed to be the default on Mac and got this:

> Input: 
>   `Macbook:~ rose$ source ./bin/activate`
>   
>  Error Message Output:
>   `-bash: ./bin/activate: No such file or directory`

NOTE: There were some other messages, here are screens of the whole shell.

[Screenshots on my GitHub Pages](https://nintendo8.github.io/Screenshots/Screenshots.html)

Comment: when creating your virtual env you shoudl do th following: virtualenv tf_env --system-site-packages -p /usr/local/bin/python3  ... as yuo can see your's screenshots does miss the name for the environment and I just provided as a sample " tf_env "

Comment: than activate the environment with source tf_env/bin/activate   here is the documentation for python3 but should work for your python2.7 version the documentation.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: so you need that folder named "tf_env" that I call "the name" of the environment but is actually a folder that will contain executable python files.

Comment: Also, when I try to install it it says

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created a virtual environment. There were errors. Please reread carefully your own screenshots, last but one and the last.

Cannot copy/paste the error message here from the images. That's one of many reasons why images without text are bad.

Comment: New problem: I did this so I could activate the (I think) now-downloaded Virtualenv environment `cd rose/tensorflow` and got this: `-bash: cd: rose/tensorflow: No such file or directory`

Comment: Things is, that folder exists

Comment: Works fine now! Did this, worked this time: `Macbook:~ rose$ cd rose/tensorflow
Macbook:tensorflow rose$ source ./bin/activate` and got
`(tensorflow) Macbook:tensorflow rose$` as my prompt, which was supposed to happen